# WPA cracking with Crunch, JTR & Aircrack

Tags: penetration-test, wifi, password-cracking

Now I assume that everyone knows of aircrack-ng and John The Ripper with it's fantastic ability to pause and resume cracking.

With that aside, I want to add Crunch into the mix, however I can't seem to add crunch to it.
The plan as goes:

**Crunch > John OR Aircrack**  [ If > John, then Crunch > John > Aircrack ]

**John > Aircrack** [ So Crunch > Aircrack & John > Aircrack ]

I am running this on the MacOSX Terminal, but I guess this doesn't matter because all three have installed successfully, however I have to `cd ~/jtr/run/` in order to use john the ripper.

Any idea on how to mix them together, anyone? If you want, I'm using `crunch 8 20 charset.lst -f mixalpha-numeric-all-space`

So far I have tried

```
./john -wordlist= -session=stpcrunch -stdout |crunch 8 20 -f ~/crunch-3.6/charset.lst mixalpha-numeric-symbol14-space -i | aircrack-ng -a 2 -b D0:57:4C:56:D2:30 -w - ~/-01.cap

crunch 8 20 -f ~/crunch-3.6/charset.lst mixalpha-numeric-symbol14-space -i |./john -wordlist= -session=stpcrunch -stdout | aircrack-ng -a 2 -b D0:57:4C:56:D2:30 -w - ~/-01.cap

./john -session=stpcrunch -stdout | crunch 8 20 mixalpha-numeric-all-space | aircrack-ng -a 2 -b D0:57:4C:56:D2:30 -w - ~/-01.cap
```

However all of these had crunch and aircrack working, however john doesn't work... I need all of them to work. - Although doing Ctrl+c stops crunch, but when ctrl+c is pressed again, it can't stop aircrack...?

Comment: (Just a side-note: Does anyone remember Crack 5.0a?)

Comment: What's Crack5.0a exactly?

Comment: A a bruteforce password cracker (mainly for Unix' /etc/shadow), that has some powerful word mangling capabilities.

Comment: Cpu cracking is dead. And you cannot save session state on a piped wordlist. Buy GPUs and a rig with at least an i3/i5+SSD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crunch (this provides the output for AirCrack) and then John (this turns it into a session) and that AirCrack (which cracks it).

Like this:

> crunch 8 20 -f ~/crunch-3.6/charset.lst mixalpha-numeric-symbol14-space -i |./john --stdin (This accepts crunch's words) --session=stpcrunch --stdout (this then forwards it to aircrack) | aircrack-ng -a 2 -b D0:57:4C:56:D2:30 -w - ~/-01.cap
>
> crunch 8 20 -f ~/crunch-3.6/charset.lst mixalpha-numeric-symbol14-space -i |./john --restore=stpcrunch | aircrack-ng -a 2 -b D0:57:4C:56:D2:30 -w - ~/-01.cap

The next time you do it, see above that the only argument you use with John is the restore option.

Answer (score 1):

> crunch 8 26 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 | aircrack-ng psk-01.cap

is an example of what you could try.

Comment: Crunch, check. Aircrack-ng, check. JTR? nope. Unless some how this can be paused and resumed?

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you try adding something like a word list from where the file is located.

1. Create a text file on your desktop
2. run `crunch` via terminal `crunch 4 4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -o /home/nameofyourcomputer/Desktop/wordlist.txt`
3. it will generate a file called `START` on your desktop
4. Now that you have a completed creating a word list of lots of possible passwords try cracking the password using `aircrack-ng` and `crunch` via `crunch 4 4 | aircrack-ng -01.cap -w /home/nameofyourcomputer/Desktop/START`
5. you wait and see if the password can be found it might take minutes or hours even days depending on your hardware

Comment: Please do not yell in posts (all caps) and take a look at the formatting options for posts.